# Spring oauth security wrong username or password 401 Unauthorized

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{

   @Override protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
   {
      http.formLogin();
      http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
   }

   @Bean
   public UserDetailsService userDetailsService()
   {
      UserDetailsManager userDetailsManager = new InMemoryUserDetailsManager();
      UserDetails user = User.withUsername("emoleumassi")
                             .password("today").authorities("write")
                             .build();
      userDetailsManager.createUser(user);
      return userDetailsManager;
   }

   @Bean
   public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder()
   {
      return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
   }

   @Bean
   @Override
   public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception
   {
      return super.authenticationManagerBean();
   }
}
```

AuthorizationServer

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter
{
   @Autowired private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

   @Override
   public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception
   {
      clients.inMemory().withClient("client").secret("secret").scopes("write").authorizedGrantTypes("password");
   }

   @Override
   public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception
   {
      endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
   }
}
```

my dependencies:

```
 SPRING_BOOT_VERSION = "2.6.6"
 implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:${SPRING_BOOT_VERSION}"
 implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:2.6.6'
 implementation 'org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2:2.5.1.RELEASE'
```

i received `401 Unauthorized`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow the oauth URLs. I think:

```
   @Override protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
  {
    http.formLogin();
    http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
    http. oauth2Login() // <-- this here
  }
```

should do it. Otherwise

```
.antMatchers("/oauth/**).permitAll()
```

might be the alternative.

Comment: i tried both but same error.

Comment: Do you have anything from the log?

Comment: just a warming `WARN  o.a.c.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase:173 - Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [263] milliseconds.`

Comment: Can you set debug logging for spring security? `logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG` or yaml equivalent